# What is this hand tool?

Tags: hand-tools

This hand tool sort of looks like a nibbler but the teeth don't seem to cut anything and the angle feels strange for that use.

When you squeeze the handle the little teeth close.
[image: tool]

[image: side]

Comment: Think it might be a crimper for tin work.  Like for making crimps on stove pipes.

Comment: Wrong dimensions for a stovepipe crimper - go look at them. OP - what have you tried to cut with it that doesn't cut? You might be working with something too thin/flexible? It looks pretty much exactly like my nibbler that needs a new jaw.

Answer (score 3):

It is called a hand nibbler, sheet metal nibbler, Parts Express Nickel Plated Nibbling Tool, and a few others. It is typically used to enlarge holes in sheet metal. It became popular because it was almost impossible to drill a square hole in a piece of metal and punches were very expensive. We used them many years ago to cut notches in radio chassis. You drill a hole, insert the tip and nibbly away. you can find them online by googling "hand nibbler". The one you show also has a notching die on the side.